# Adobe CS5 compatibilty with new OS on iMac

Tags: imac, snow-leopard, adobe, compatibility

I have an iMac running OS X 10.6.8. I need to update the operating system as I can't update search engines etc. but am worried if I do CS5 Adobe suite won't run (I also have Microsoft 2008). I need both for my job.

Happy to update to not the latest OS, but just enough to make sure I can access the web (already can't do Linkedin).

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: What iMac model do you have?

Comment: I needed to do a special Java download from Apple before CS5 would work on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running 10.6.8, you have at least an Early 2006 iMac (but not earlier because that would make it a G5 which renders this whole thing moot).  It also can't be any later than a Late-2009 since that was the last model that could support 10.6.x

If it's a 2006, you are pretty much dead in the water so to speak and it's time to buy a new iMac because the most you are going to upgrade to is 10.7.5

So, I am going on the assumption that you have a 2007 or later iMac....

---

You are right on the cusp of being able to upgrade to macOS Sierra if you have a *2009* ([macOS Sierra How to Upgrade](http://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/)).  However, I don't recommend you going that far.  In my personal experience, *the problems associated with Sierra have far outweighed any potential benefits I never needed in the first place* so I advise skipping or waiting out this version.

Regardless, you **must** upgrade to El Capitan first; just stay here for now.

As for CS5, there's not too many [known issues](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-and-el-capitan-mac-os-10-11.html), but generally it appears that it works.  Though CS5 is 7 years old, so, it's highly unlikely you will find very much way in the development of "fixes" for any outstanding issues.

> Happy to update to not the latest OS, but just enough to make sure I can access the web (already can't do Linkedin). What should I do? Thanks!

Since your particular iMac (*assumed*) is capable of running El Capitan, I would suggest only a couple of hardware upgrades:

- Max out memory (depending on your model, this can go from 6GB to 32GB)
- Add an SSD (I personally use and recommend the [Samsung 850 EVO](http://radnex.us/Samsung_EVO_850); I use it in my iMac)
- Do a full Time Machine backup and do a fresh clean install (preferably on the new SSD) to ensure you are starting from "factory."

[ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_Intel_27%22_EMC_2390) has an excellent guide for opening your machine (the 2007 - 2011 iMac's used magnets to hold the display in so removal is actually fairly easy)

Bottom Line:  As long as your iMac is at least from 2007 onward, you have a bit more life that can be extracted from your machine as it supports at least El Capitan.  A few dollars spent on upgrading your hardware will speed things up and breathe new life into it.